# Using linux to access resources through windows machine

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, vpn

I have a windows 10 machine already set up to have access to some resources (various domains and subdomains) based on the machines ip (and probably other network stuff). Then, on the same network I have ubuntu linux machine on which I want to connect to these resources, e.g. gitlab.example.com. These resources aren't visible to this ubuntu machine.

Is it possible to create some setup that if I type the address in my ubuntu browser, it connects through the windows machine and returns the resources? If so, how to setup it?

I know that I can install vpn server on the windows machine and use it this way. But sometimes I work from home and I use already one vpn to connect to work network only to see the machines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to achieve this using SSH:

Set up an SSH server on the Windows machine:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Then route web traffic through this SSH server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel

Comment: Yeah, this sounds good. But it looks like app by app specific solution. I would like sth system wide. For example to use other apps like git, intellij idea, etc...

Comment: In that case, I think you should look again at VPNs